# How to Add/Remove New Server behind Haproxy with Minimal Disruption

Tags: linux, tcp, load-balancing, iptables, haproxy

Haproxy is currently balancing the load between 2 servers, `A` an `B`. Clients are connecting to these servers via persistent TCP connections.

**Question:** We want to upgrade from server `A` to a more powerful server `C`. How can we add a 3rd server `C` and remove `A` without disrupting/disconnecting the client? If `iptables` is used to redirect connections from `A` to `C`, will it still work if we shut down `A` at some point, or is `A` required to stay online to continue redirecting existing clients to `C`?

Comment: Off topic. Try serverfault.com.

Answer (score 4):

For the first question: how to add a third server.  Changing the haproxy configuration to add C will require a restart of the load balancer.  But, http://www.mgoff.in/2010/04/18/haproxy-reloading-your-config-with-minimal-service-impact/ says that a combination of -st and -sf command line arguments will minimize the disruption by allowing the haproxy instances to hand off the ports they listen to.  Implementing this may require that you change your haproxy init.d script.

For the second: If you use a firewall to block A then traffic bound for A will go to B and C or just to C, depending on the haproxy configuration.  This may disrupt a bit of customer traffic if the sessions have stickiness.  If the application's sessions are stateless then the changes will be invisible to clients.  If you shut down A after blocking its traffic then your customers will not notice.

Comment: Thank you. So in the config file I have removed the first server and added the third server and did a `haproxy reload`. However I notice that most of the clients are still connected to the first server through the haproxy, only a few are connected to the third server probably after disconnections initiated client side. How should I redirect the clients currently connected to first server over to the other two servers so that we can be shut down the first server without disconnecting the clients?